# Error in building app with react-hook-form using TS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I get the following error when I try to build my react app using react-hook-form in TS:

```
node_modules/react-hook-form/dist/types/utils.d.ts:24:77 - error TS1005: '?' expected.

24 declare type PathImpl<K extends string | number, V> = V extends Primitive ? `${K}` : `${K}` | `${K}.${Path<V>}`;
                                                                               ~~~

node_modules/react-hook-form/dist/types/utils.d.ts:24:84 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

24 declare type PathImpl<K extends string | number, V> = V extends Primitive ? `${K}` : `${K}` | `${K}.${Path<V>}`;
                                                                                      ~

node_modules/react-hook-form/dist/types/utils.d.ts:24:110 - error TS1005: '(' expected.

24 declare type PathImpl<K extends string | number, V> = V extends Primitive ? `${K}` : `${K}` | `${K}.${Path<V>}`;
```

And here's my build command:

```
yarn tsc --emitDeclarationOnly && tsc-alias -p tsconfig.json
```

Here's my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "jsx": "react",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@context/*": [
        "context/*"
      ],
      "@types": [
        "types/index.ts"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/",
    "./src/**/*.stories.tsx",
    "./src/**/*.test.tsx",
    "./src/**/__mocks__/**/*"
  ]
}
```

I'm using react-hook-form version 7.6.6. Any suggestion on how to fix this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hi, can you share a codesandbox, please?

Answer (score 13):

According to this [discussion](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/discussions/3359#discussioncomment-587331), `react-hook-form` v7 needs TS 4.1 above

Comment: Thx for your answer, could you also provide more information about the how to update to such version? It may help others ;)

Comment: @RaphaëlBalet if you are using npm, you can use the command "npm i typescript@4.1.6"

Comment: yarn add typescript@latest

Answer (score 1):

As @nathaniaelvina pointed out check your package.json if you have a typescript version bellow v4.

If typescript is bellow v4 run the following:

```
npm i typescript@4.5.4
```

where 4.5.4 is the latest version from https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript

Note that after the typescript update there might be some changes needed to get it compiling again.